# A globetrotting riddle, with a twist

Tags: riddle, knowledge, language

<sub>This is an entry into [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36: Twisted Classics 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/fortnightly-topic-challenge-36-twisted-classics-1). First time doing an FTC, so let me know what you think.</sub>

*Let's take a little trip around the world, shall we? Make sure to write me when you get there!*

My first's in Rhode Island and certainly in Greece
My second's in Gotthard, Odisha holds this piece
My third's in Bethlehem or Deseret I vow
My fourth is in Bahrain, and living with the Miao
My fifth's in Savannah, mixed with the Cherokee
My sixth is in Bismarck, hidden among the Cree
My seventh's in Vineyard; at home in Morocco
My eighth's in Bar Harbor, and mingling with the Ho

Put them all together and I hope you will see
**To answer this riddle, what will you have to be?**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The trick to this is that

> we're not extracting letters common to each pair of words, as you'd usually do in these types of puzzles. Instead, the second in each pair hints at a writing system of some sort, and the first has a letter in it. For instance, "in Greece" tells us that we're looking for a Greek letter, and right at the start we have **Rho**de Island.

The letters you get from each line are

> **Rho**de Island (Greek alphabet)
>  Go**ttha**rd ([Odia alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odia_alphabet))
>  B**eth**lehem ([Deseret Alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deseret_alphabet#/media/File:Deseret_chart_in_Book_of_Mormon_1869.png))
>  B**ah**rain  ([Pollard Miao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard_script))
>  Savan**nah** ([Cherokee Syllabary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherokee_syllabary))
>  Bis**ma**rck ([Cree Syllabary](http://www.omniglot.com/writing/cree.htm))
>  Vine**yar**d ([Tifinagh](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/tamazight.htm))
>  Bar **Har**bor ([Warang Citi, Ho language](https://www.omniglot.com/writing/varangkshiti.htm))

These letters, when put together, clearly spell out our answer:

> [image]
>  You need to be a **POLYGLOT**!

Comment: Booya. Nice work; I hope those weren't too hard to get.

Comment: @SKOG Once I realized there was a single canonical source that would clear up character name ambiguities, not hard at all! It was a really nice puzzle, and definitely a fun twist on the usual genre.